# get how much days using strtotime format in php

Tags: php

can someone help add something missing at this code?

```
$turnback=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.  *here the missing code* .' days', strtotime($d['borrowdate'])));
// get turn back date where borrow date + how long borrowing

$date1=date_create($turnback); // turnback date
$date2=date_create($d['turnbackdate']); // turnback date
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
$late= $diff->d;
```

i have try like this :

```
$turnback= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$d['turnbackdate'].' days', strtotime($d['borrowdate'])));

$date1=date_create($d['borrowdate']);
$date2=date_create($d['turnbackdate']);
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
$telat = $diff->d;
```

but can't more make more than 1 month
like 2 january to 3 march, the output is 1 days

Comment: What exactly you want to do.

Comment: there is missing code after +, what should i add after that +

Comment: please ensure you accept the answer if it helped you so others that come across it can also be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), you're just fetching the day *component* of the diff with `$diff->d`

You'll want to use something similar to this example lifted from the documentation.

```php
$origin = date_create('2009-10-11');
$target = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($origin, $target);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

That will output:

> +2 days

Presumably, that will work for you almost straight out of the box with the `%R` showing `+`/`-` as appropriate.